# Is it recommended to use seperate database for forms authentication for MVC4 project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

One database for the project and once for the authentication created by the MVC4 template.

*Reply to  Mystere Man:*

I was following this [MVC4 example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/using-web-api-with-entity-framework,-part-1):

It creates two connection strings in web.config file, one for forms authentication and the other one for product database.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ProductStore-20120829112625;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ProductStore-20120829112625.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="OrdersContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=OrdersContext-20120829131625; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|OrdersContext-20120829131625.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 4):

No.  It's not recommended, but it's not "not reccomended" either.  You can put your membership tables anywhere you want.  What's recommended is to put them where you want them.

But frankly, I see no valid reason to use a separate database, other than personal preference.  I personally think it's pointless to put them somewhere else.  Now you have to backup two databases and keep the backups synchronized.

Comment: Exactly my point!  But I have seen couple of examples on MSDN with two databases.

Comment: @WinFXGuy - do you have any examples?